# Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int';

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

passing id value to controller gives an error " Failed to convert the value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'".

but when I print System.out.println(studentService.findById(id)) it give a output in terminal as
Optional[Student{id=1, firstName='Abhishek', lastName='Shukla', branch='CS', year=4, mobileNumber='9876543210'}]

I already tried to pass the id as a string and convert string to int by using Integr.parseInt(id)  in the controller but it throws an error as 
 " Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{id}"] with root cause "

```
    <h1>Student Place</h1>
    <form name="myForm" action="/student/{id}" >
        <table border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Student ID :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="id" size="10" /> </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
         <br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /><br>
        <input type="reset" value="Rest" name="reset" />
     </form>
```

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService  ;

    @GetMapping(value = "/students")
    public  String index(ModelMap modelMap){
        modelMap.put("students" , studentService.findAll());
        return "index" ;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/student/{id}")
    public String data(@PathVariable("id") int id , ModelMap modelMap){
        modelMap.put("students" , studentService.findById(id)) ;
        System.out.println(studentService.findById(id));

        return "studentbyid" ;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/student")
    public String databyid(){
        return "student" ;
    }
}
```

```
public interface StudentService {

    public Iterable<Student> findAll() ;
    public Optional<Student> findById(int id) ;
}
```

```
@Transactional
@Service("studentService")
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository ;

    @Override
    public Iterable<Student> findAll() {
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<Student> findById(int id) {
        return studentRepository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id ;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName ;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName ;

    @Column(name="branch")
    private String branch ;

    @Column(name="year")
    private int  year ;

    @Column(name="mobile_number")
    private String mobileNumber ;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String branch, int year, String mobileNumber) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.branch = branch;
        this.year = year;
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getBranch() {
        return branch;
    }

    public void setBranch(String branch) {
        this.branch = branch;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", branch='" + branch + '\'' +
                ", year=" + year +
                ", mobileNumber='" + mobileNumber + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{id}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action of your form is

```
action="/student/{id}"
```

So, as the error message shows, you are literally sending a request to `/student/{id}` instead of, let's say, `/student/1234`.

Since apparently, the form has an input field where the user must enter the ID, the ID will be sent as a request parameter, not as a path variable, so the path of your controller method and of your action should simply be

```
/students
```

and it should take the ID as a request parameter:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/student")
public String data(@RequestParam("id") int id, ModelMap modelMap)
```

Comment: how to pass a value from jsp form as @PathVariable

Comment: In your case, you would need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

please check properties file and ensure you didn't put semicolon(;) after specifying property

Answer (score 0):

Try using @RequestParam instead of @PathVariable as you're already sending `<input name = "id">`, so

Like, that's a parameter you're already sending, so you should fetch it as a param, not as Path Variable.

Once you do so, keep the url as `/students`
instead of `/students/{id}`

Should work then.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).